# Proof that the coefficient on a binary predictor in a simple OLS is equal to difference in means of the outcome for that predictor?

Tags: regression, least-squares

In an univariate least squares regression the regression equation is given by:

```
y = a + bx
```

where `b` is the slope coefficient of the predictor, i.e.

```
b = r(Sy/Sx) = mean(y[x=1]) - mean(y[x=0])
```

where `r` is Pearson's correlation coefficient (`sum((x-xbar)(y-ybar))/(sum(x-xbar)^2 * sum(y-ybar)^2)`) and `S` represents the standard deviations of `x` and `y`, respectively (and you could optionally add a `+ e` to represent the error term).

If `x` is binary (e.g. 0 or 1 for simplicity), then I know that `b` is equivalent to the mean of `y` where `x` = 1 minus the mean of `y` where `x` = 0. In other words:

```
b = r(Sy/Sx) = mean(y[x=1]) - mean(y[x=0])
```

I can plug in real data to see that. But how can it be shown as a proof rather than just observing it with arbitrary real data plugged in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In statistic, we do not have a perfect equation like $y=\alpha+\beta x$, instead, we assume a model of a form
$$y=\alpha+\beta x + \varepsilon,$$
where $\varepsilon\sim N(0, \sigma^2)$ (or in general $E(\varepsilon)=0$ and $Var(\varepsilon) = \sigma^2$).
This equation implies that $E(y\mid x) = \alpha+\beta x$. If $x$ is binary, then
$E(y\mid x=0) = \alpha$ and $E(y\mid x=1) = \alpha+\beta$. We then have:
$$E(y\mid x=1) - E(y\mid x=0) = \beta.$$

Comment: Thank you. I was originally trying to relate the answer to Pearson's correlation coefficient and the other terms, but this will do I think. Could you say how it changes in multiple regression such that you may have a different coefficient for `b` and thus this is no longer necessarily true?

Comment: What do you mean by "a different coefficient" for $\beta$?

Comment: I mean that in an OLS regression if I start adding in other terms B2 X2, B3 X3, for new vectors of data it may (almost always does) change the estimated coefficient for our original vector `x` so it would no longer be true that the mean(Y[x=1])-mean(Y[x=0]) = B

Comment: For example, in R using the built-in `iris` data set this simple OLS regression obeys what we discussed above: `summary(glm(Sepal.Width~ I(Sepal.Length>5),data=iris))` however when I add in more terms the coefficient on the original binary vector changes and it no longer obeys the relationship: `summary(glm(Sepal.Width~ I(Sepal.Length>5)+Petal.Width,data=iris))` because a portion of the original variance in the outcome associated with the binary predictor is now partitioned into the new explanatory variable

Comment: It is still correct if there no interaction terms related to $X_1$ and in the expectation, you need to control for other variable. Please see my answer here (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/486387/why-do-we-not-interpret-main-effects-if-interaction-terms-are-significant-in-ano/486388#486388).

Comment: Thanks, that's related but not quite the same as what I'm asking. I can open a new question for it though, you answered my original question. Thank you.

Comment: Please note that your example is at the sample level, what we are talking is at the population level.

Comment: I posted it here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/500616/express-how-additional-covariates-in-a-multiple-regression-may-affect-the-coeffi  I used synthetic data to illustrate it there.