# How to best interpret factorial design results?

Tags: r, anova, experiment-design

I am analysing data from a 2^3 factorial design in R. I am using blocking, and I was wondering if my reasoning is correct. I am testing reaction time in milliseconds with three factors (Type of test, Hand temperature, and Dominant/NonDominant Hand).

Here is the output for the model:
[image]

1. For the "block" variable, am I correct in saying that we do not observe significant evidence that there is a difference in mean reaction time between the two blocks? And do I just remove this variable from my model?
2. For the "temp:hand" interaction, do I remove it from the model as well? Or I retain it and state that the interaction between temperature and hand is not significant?

Comment: If you test for a third-level interaction (`test:temp:hand`) it doesn't typically make sense to interpret or test any lower-level terms. See this question for example https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/486387/why-do-we-not-interpret-main-effects-if-interaction-terms-are-significant-in-ano#:~:text=It%20is%20because%20the%20effect,Z%20(through%20the%20interaction). Perhaps it would make more sense to calculate a linear model and look at the model predictions and effect sizes.

Comment: So would I just keep this model and not remove any variables?

Comment: Yes, you should leave these terms in the model, and only interpret the "top level" term. Most of the time if you want to interpret an interaction term, all of the lower level terms should be in the model as well.

Comment: Okay thank you! So in terms of a mathematical model would it look like yhat = B0 + B1(Block) + B2(test) + B3(temp) + B4(hand) + B5(test)(temp) + B6(test)(hand) + B7(temp)(hand) + B8(test)(temp)(hand) + error?